# System of equations involving lcm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Given a system:

$$
\begin{cases}
5x - 3y = 0 \\
\text{lcm}(x, y) = 45
\end{cases}
$$

Since, $5x=3y$, I've tried expressing product of $xy$ as:

$$
\text{lcm}(x,y)\gcd(x,y)=xy \\
\gcd(x,y)=\frac{xy}{\text{lcm}(x,y)}
$$

I see that $x = 9$ and $y = 15$, I understand that we get it from dividing $\text{lcm}(x,y)$ which is 45 by coefficients, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Well, there aren't very many pairs $(x,y)$ with $\text {lcm}(x,y)=45$, you could just try all of them.  And you know $3\,|\,x$ and $5\,|\,y$ which narrows the list further.

Comment: By the linked [LCM Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/2420) we can scale by $\,\color{#c00}3\,$ so we can use $\,\color{#c00}{3y=5x}\,$ to *eliminate* $\,y\,$ yielding 
$$3\cdot 45 = 3\,{\rm lcm}(x,y) = {\rm lcm}(3x,\color{#c00}{3y}) = {\rm lcm}(3x,\color{#c00}{5x}) = {\rm lcm}(3,5)x = 15x\ \Rightarrow\ x = 9\qquad$$

Comment: Alternatively we can work with prime factorizations of $\,x,y\mid {\rm lcm}(x,y)=45\,$ as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2678055/242) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/894818/242) or the answer below, or *many* other prior answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathrm{lcm}(x, y) = 45$, then we know both $x$ and $y$ are factors of 45, so $x = 3^{a_1} 5^{b_1}$ and $y = 3^{a_2} 5^{b_2}$ with $\max(a_1, a_2) = 2$ and $\max(b_1, b_2) = 1$.

We also know that $5x = 3y$, so $3^{a_1} 5^{b_1 + 1} = 3^{a_2 + 1} 5^{b_2}$. Which then implies that $a_1 > a_2$ and $b_2 > b_1$, forcing both of those to be equal to the maximums, i.e. $a_1 = 2$ and $b_2 = 1$ which is enough to give us the solution.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).